# ASP.NET MVC Core how to get application supported culture list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

In my Startup.cs I added two cultures:

```
       var cultureLt = new CultureInfo("LT");
       var cultureEn = new CultureInfo("EN");
       var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {cultureEn, cultureLt};

       var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions();
       requestLocalizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider());
       requestLocalizationOptions.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
       requestLocalizationOptions.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

       app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions);
```

I need to get this list in constructor and now in consturctor controller I initialized variable

```
private readonly IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> _locOptions;
```

and in Action I'm trying to get this list like this:

```
var cultureItems = _locOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
            .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
            .ToList();
```

but the problem is that this line only returns the culture that is currently set in application... How to get both EN and LT cultures?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must configure the RequestLocalizationOptions.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{         
     // ... enter code here

     // RequestLocalizationOptions must to be configured 
     var cultureLt = new CultureInfo("LT");
     var cultureEn = new CultureInfo("EN");
     var supportedCultures = new[] { cultureEn, cultureLt };

     services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
     {
         options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
         options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
     });

     // Add them to IServiceCollection
     services.AddLocalization();

     // ... enter code here
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ... enter code here

    // add RequestLocalizationMiddleware to pipeline
    app.UseRequestLocalization();

    app.UseMvc...
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue (asp.net core 3), anyway the manner I'm creating my LocalizationOptions (AddSupportedCultures, options.SupportedCultures), the list contains only the current culture

Comment: .net 5. Solved. Moved configuration from Configure to ConfigureServices and it works like a charm.

Comment: @wondertalik What's different about this in .net 5 (vs. core 3.1)?

Comment: @HappyNomad, in this case is the same. But there are many small changes. You can read about on the [official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dotnet-five).